# array intilization needs curly braces

Tags: arrays, c++11, vector

following code gives error array **intilization needs curly braces**

If I wanted to create two dimentional array and add it in to vector than how to do it?

```
vector<char[4][4]> testCases;
for(double i =0;i<noOFTestCase;i++)
{
    char arr[4][4];
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        cin>>(arr[j]);
    }
    testCases.push_back(arr);
}
```

Comment: You can't have an array as a vector element - arrays are not copyable nor movable. You could define a struct that has an array as its sole member, then put that into the vector.

Comment: Or use `std::array`, which amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ramzah Rehman mentioned, there are constraints on what you can put in vector. They must have defined copy constructor and initialisation constructor semantics.

Without defining your copy and/or initialization constructors (and destructors) the data in the objects would be random when the vector class added/removed or moved items.

What you could do is create a class with your testCases as a property, and write the appropriate constructors.

You could try using a vector of vectors of string instead, because the string class already implements copyable semantics.

for example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

template<int N> class TestCase : public vector<string>
{
  public:
  TestCase() { resize(N); }
  static const int size() { return N; }
};

typedef TestCase<4> MyTestCase;

int main()
{
  vector<MyTestCase> testCases;

  for(int i =0;i<noOfTestCases;i++)
  {
    MyTestCase arr;

    for(int j=0;j< MyTestCase::size();j++)
    {
      std::cin>>(arr[j]);
    }
    testCases.push_back(arr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vectors can't have arrays as data members.